# How to monitor jboss6.4.9 with jmx in zabbix 3.2

Tags: jmx, jboss6.x, zabbix

I enabled JMX in JBoss it works fine with jconsole. How to monitor JBoss with JMX in Zabbix.
my JBoss version: 6.4.9
Zabbix version: 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zabbix 3.2 does not support `remoting-jmx`, used by JBoss, without patching the product. You should upgrade to 3.4 which [introduced support for configurable JMX endpoints](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1274).